# use macros in presentation compiler

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, macros

I am using macros to add synthetic companion objects (with `apply` method and other stuff) to annotated classes. Such as

```
@myTransform class Foo(i: Int)
```

that will output

```
object Foo {
  def apply(i: Int): Foo = new Foo(i)
}
class Foo(i: Int)
```

Now if I write in the source code of a sub-project that depends on these macros, `Foo(1234)`, this is highlighted as error by IntelliJ IDEA.

Is it possible to configure the presentation compiler of IntelliJ IDEA to respect these kind of macros and invoke them to operate on the properly transformed code, avoiding these highlighting errors?

Comment: I have a project where I have tried to do something similar, but with standard JavaBeans (see https://github.com/yetu/scala-beanutils). However, I had the same problem, I believe it is not possible unless you want to write an IntelliJ plugin (such as the one for Lombok)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IntelliJ Scala plugin now has an API for macro support: https://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2015/10/14/intellij-api-to-build-scala-macros-support/